# Single word for lazy student

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word for "lazy student". In my own language there is such a word that a teacher would use for a student who doesn't engage and doesn't care. In English, the word "slacker" is the best I could think of.

Comment: sounds very close to a *regular* student ;-)

Comment: sloth? also $muff$

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the word in your language and how does it translate into English [literally]?

Comment: I'd go for mismanaged or unmanaged.

Comment: I believe the word you're looking for is freshman.

Comment: underachiever.  This sounds politically correct, and I don't want to be politically correct.  But there are a lot of reasons a student might be an underachiever -- from dyslexia to a boring teacher.  For over a million years, we learned by doing.  The classroom is very artificial.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Slacker** — [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/slacker)

> a person who evades his or her duty or work

**Good-for-nothing** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/good-for-nothing)

> A person of little worth or usefulness.

**Couch potato** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/couch+potato)

> an idler who spends much time on a couch (usually watching television)

<sub>Couldn't find any word specifically tailored for students. Aren't most students like this anyway?</sub>

Comment: There are nuances in all these words. Maybe the answer would be more useful if the words were grouped by their meaning. For instance, "lead-swinger" means "someone who dodges work, while pretending to be busy doing it", if I understand correctly from the dictionary, while an "idler", just sits around doing nothing.

Comment: @user3653831 Maybe if you provide more context in the question, I could narrow it down.

Comment: When I wrote the question, I only wanted a word for a lazy graduate student who would not do his research work, but, somehow, he'd always convince his adviser he was doing a great job. I didn't expect a single word for that, so I asked the question above.

Comment: @user3653831 Again, that describes me. I'm one month away from thesis submission, yet procrastinating like there's no tomorrow. I'm not even sure what describes me perfectly. *Engineer*, I guess. ;)

Comment: When you add "graduate student", what changes?  You may find some ideas in the discussion of 'ABD' students [All But Dissertation].

Answer (score 9):

I think ***[slacker](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=slacker%20definition)*** works the best here:

> a person who avoids work or effort

[Google]

Comment: Once again a focus on the person and not the behaviour. Not constructive.

Answer (score 2):

[indolent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indolent) Disinclined to exert oneself; habitually lazy.

from: Motivating Unmotivated Students http://www.ascd.org/ascd-express/vol5/504-reeves.aspx

"Many students think that they already know how to "play school"—keep your head down, don't bother the teachers, and do the minimum necessary. This path of least resistance is typified by the **indolent student**, who in turn is part of a society that is, in Robert Bork’s (1996) memorable phrase, "slouching toward Gomorrah. ..."

Answer (score 2):

I may go for "procrastinator"
definition: is a person who delays or puts things off — like work, chores, or other actions — that should be done in a timely manner.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, [***dunce***](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/cancre)

> : a dull-witted, stupid, or ignorant person.
>
> [1520–30; after John Duns Scotus, whose writings were attacked by the humanists as foolish]
>
> [Random House Kennerman Webster's Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dunce)
>
> : a bad and lazy student.
>
> [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/cancre); [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/cancre/12650)
>
> ***Einstein, Churchill, and Hitler were dunces in school.***
>
> [dunce cap](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/gros-branleur.1048013/?hl=fr) *or* dunce's cap
>
> A tall, cone-shaped hat formerly worn by slow [**or lazy students**](http://www.victorianschool.co.uk/dunce.html) as a punishment in school (emphasis is mine.)
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dunce-cap)

Also, consider [***jerk(-off)***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22cancre%22&biw=1024&bih=672&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGv-LM_5TMAhVEqxoKHeRPDoEQ_AUIBCgA&dpr=2#q=%22a+jerk+in+school%22), [***goof-off***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22cancre%22&biw=1024&bih=672&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGv-LM_5TMAhVEqxoKHeRPDoEQ_AUIBCgA&dpr=2#q=%22a+goof-off+in+school%22), [***lazy bastard***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22cancre%22&biw=1024&bih=672&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGv-LM_5TMAhVEqxoKHeRPDoEQ_AUIBCgA&dpr=2#q=%22lazy+bastard+in+school%22), [***lazy bum***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22cancre%22&biw=1024&bih=672&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGv-LM_5TMAhVEqxoKHeRPDoEQ_AUIBCgA&dpr=2#q=%22lazy+bum+in+s,school%22), and [***tool***](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/branleur.519336/?hl=fr)

> jerk-off/jerkoff
>
> : *Slang: Vulgar.* a stupid, bumbling, foolish, **or lazy person**; jerk (emphasis is mine.)
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/jerk-off)
>
> goof-off
>
> *Slang.* One who shirks work or responsibility.
>
> [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/goof-off)
>
> bum
>
> A bum is defined as a person who is lazy and does not work by choice.
>
> [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/bum#vv1UfR18cixbO7pX.99)
>
> A person who does no work; *a lazy bum*
>
> [Farlex Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bum)

Comment: Someone who is not smart may well be a very hard worker.

Comment: None of these would be used by a native speaker. Most of the words mean something else now. Bum = tramp, jerk-off = wanker etc. @NVZ's answer and its synonyms are in widespread use.

Comment: @Elian There is a nuanced but significant difference between lazy-bum and bum. Lazy is the operative word. There's a difference between knowing English and being able to search for words on other fourums. I don't want to sound like a git but I see too many upvotes on this site for manifestly incorrect answers.