# Are there any cool slang words for "couch potato"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, slang

Seems like this word is a bit old-fashioned. What do youngsters call lazy procrastinators nowadays?

Comment: Related: [Synonym for “slacker”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84881/synonym-for-slacker) and [Single word for lazy student](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319926/single-word-for-lazy-student) and [Word meaning “the act of intending to do nothing”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48016/word-meaning-the-act-of-intending-to-do-nothing)

Comment: and finally [How to define someone who does not like/want to get a job or do anything in life?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172476/how-to-define-someone-who-does-not-like-want-to-get-a-job-or-do-anything-in-life/172576#172576)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'couch potato'? (Don't assume that people will share you view)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Slakka**, or the plural term, **Slakkas**.

It's a new hip and cool phrase.

Comment: Do you have any evidence?